# “Someone who is disinclined to work”

Tags: word-request, nouns

What do you call the one who is disinclined to work, but when their senior comes before them, they begin to act they are hardworking?

> The manager, after inspecting the office, found that three employees were___ and gossiped throughout the day.

Comment: The three employees were **shirking**.

Comment: Weather Vane, I googled so many times and came across the word: “Lazybones”. Does it convey the meaning I want?

Comment: @JayHo *Lazybones* is a very informal kind of insult.  I would expect to see it in a sentence like *Get back to work, lazybones!* but not in a more formal sentence describing what a manager found.

Comment: As Weather Vane says. Or, more informally, they were **skiving**.

Comment: "Work-shy" or about a million other words and phrases.

Comment: A lazybones may not even bother to pretend to be working, whereas skiving can be a skilled art.

Answer (score 1):

They’re [slackers](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/slacker), or someone “who shirks work or responsibility.” It is fairly informal, and in a different context can imply more than just laziness, as the other definitions from that link explain.

> The manager, after inspecting the office, found that three employees were **slackers** and gossiped throughout the day.

I often [“slack” or “slack off”](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/slack) on the weekends when I should be doing household chores. It’s mildly disparaging. My husband and I often call ourselves slackers as a joke. It would not be appropriate if you’re looking for something formal, or more strongly disapproving.